# Transforming and then projecting a box

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, matrix-equations

For any positive integer $d$ define the box $B_d$ as all points $(x_1, ..., x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $|x_i| < 1.$

Suppose I have some invertible $n \times n$ matrix $M_1$, and for an integer $k<n$ I have the $k \times n$ projection matrix $P$ which projects a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ by removing the last $n-k$ components.

So I can look at the set $PM_1B_n$, which is transforming and then projecting the box $B_d$. Is it true that $PM_1B_n = M_2B_k$ for some invertible $k \times k$ matrix $M_2$? That is, if I transform and then project the box $B_n$, is that always equal to a transformation of the lower dimensional box $B_k$?

I can't seem to come up with a situation where the projection collapses things to lower than $k$ dimensions, but I am not certain that this should hold either...

Comment: You can turn a cube such that it projects to a hexagon in the plane. Would that not be a counterexample? 
I’m assuming $n$ and $d$ are the same